# Tensorflow restored model gives different results

Tags: tensorflow, restore

I have recently been working on word2vec within tensor flow and it works well so I decided to try to save and load it but when I restore the model it gives different results.  It does this every time I restore it.  Here is my code
https://github.com/drok0920/cobalt/tree/master
I am sorry if i am improperly using terms as I am relatively new to this topic.